# Switching the texts between three labels back and forth with a button

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I was wondering how I could switch the text between three labels, repeatedly, back and forth, with the press of a button.

Comment: I'd use Java code for that. For a more specific answer, show what **you** have tried in the form of a [mcve]. Don't forget to add a specific (or any, for that matter) question in your [edit].

Comment: This question is broad and vague. Is the switching cyclic or random or depends on some condition?
In which ever fashion the switching should occur, you'd have to manipulate the labels' text in the event listener of the button (for example, click or press listener, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Random();` to choose Random JLabels and Random words.

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

public class randomDAMN extends JFrame {

randomDAMN() {
    JButton b1 = new JButton("Change");
    JLabel l1 = new JLabel();
    JLabel l2 = new JLabel();
    JLabel l3 = new JLabel();
    ArrayList<Object> o = new ArrayList<Object>();
    String[] word1 = { "Why", "Damn", "Woah", "this", "hell", "question" };
    Random r = new Random();
    add(l1);
    add(l2);
    add(l3);
    add(b1);
    o.add(l1);
    o.add(l2);
    o.add(l3);
    b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int selectLabel = r.nextInt(o.size());
            int selecteditem = r.nextInt(word1.length);
            abc a = new abc(selectLabel, o, word1, selecteditem);
            a.ran();
        }
    });
    setSize(300, 300);
    setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1));
    setResizable(false);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new randomDAMN();
    }
}

class abc {
    int selectLabel;
    ArrayList<Object> o;
    String[] word1;
    int selecteditem;

    abc(int selectLabel, ArrayList<Object> o, String[] word1, int selecteditem) {
        this.selectLabel = selectLabel;
        this.o = o;
        this.word1 = word1;
        this.selecteditem = selecteditem;
    }

    void ran(){
        ((JLabel) o.get(selectLabel)).setText(word1[selecteditem]);
    }
}
```